# Parallel Arrays in a for loop

Tags: java

It's my 2nd week in Java.

**The problem:**

Write an application for Cody’s Car Care Shop that shows a user a list of available services: oil change, tire rotation, battery check, or brake inspection. Allow the user to enter a string that corresponds to one of the options, and display the option and its price as $25, $22, $15, or $5, accordingly. Display Invalid Entry if the user enters an invalid item.

As you can see in my comments on bottom most part of the code, my program still produce invalid entries. Please overhaul or modify my code in order to meet the requirements(You must use parallel arrays - Prof).

```
import java.util.*;
public class CarCareChoice {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String[] offers =  { "oil change", "tire rotation",
         "battery check", "brake inspection"};
        
        int[] prices = {25, 22, 15, 5};
        
        System.out.println("Enter Selection:");
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        
        for(int x = 0; x < prices.length; ++x){
             if(offers[x].equals(choice)){
                System.out.println(offers[x] +" price is $" + prices[x]);
             }
             else{
                  System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
             }                            
        }            
    }
}

//input: oil change

/*output:
oil change price is $25
Invalid Entry
Invalid Entry
Invalid Entry*/
```

Comment: You need to break out of the loop if the condition is met.

Comment: "*Please overhaul or modify my code in order to meet the requirements(You must use parallel arrays - Prof).*" - This is not how Stack overflow works. We are not a code writing service. I recommend taking the [tour] and reading the [help] page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use return statement for your requirement.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CarCareChoice {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String[] offers =  { "oil change", "tire rotation",
         "battery check", "brake inspection"};
        
        int[] prices = {25, 22, 15, 5};
        
        System.out.println("Enter Selection:");
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        
        
        for(int x = 0; x < prices.length; ++x){
             if(offers[x].equals(choice)){
                System.out.println(offers[x] +" price is $" + prices[x]);
                return;
             }
        }  
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the choice is either of the 4 options, try doing a break;